# An interesting exponential integral problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, exponential-function

Suppose $a : [0 , 1] \to \Bbb R$ is an infinitely smooth function. For $\lambda\ge1$, define $$F(\lambda) := \lambda \int_0^1 e^{\lambda t} a(t) \, dt.$$
If $\sup_{\lambda\ge1}|F(\lambda)|\lt\infty$, then $a$ is the identically zero function.

My professor said this assertion is true but I haven't been able to solve this for some time. He also implied that this problem is highly non-trival (at least for me).  Below are the some results I have derived:

1. Derivatives of any order of $a$ vanishes at $t = 1.$
2. For any $\delta\lt1$, $a(t)$ has a zero in the open interval $(\delta , 1).$ 
   The same is true for all the derivatives of $a(t)$. This tells us that the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $a$ has infinitely many distinct zeros for all natural $n$.
3. If $a$ is analytic, then I can show that $a(t)\equiv 0.$
4. If $a(t)\ge0$ on $[0 , 1]$, then it is obvious that $a\equiv 0.$

I would appreciate any hint.

Actually $(1)$ and $(3)$ follows from $(2)$. For $(2)$, suppose that $a(1)\gt0$ (the case that $a(1)\lt0$ can be argued in the same way as the following), then there exists $\delta\lt1$ such that $a(t)$ is strictly positive on $I = [1-\delta , 1]$. Then write $F(\lambda) = \lambda\int_0^{1-\delta}e^{\lambda t}a(t)dt + \lambda\int_{1-\delta}^1e^{\lambda t}a(t)dt$. Now there exists $c\gt0$ such that $a(t)>c$ on $I$ since $I$ is compact, so that the second term is bounded below by $c (e^{\lambda}-e^{\lambda(1-\delta)})$. But the first term is only $O(e^{\lambda(1-\delta)})$, so this contradicts the fact that $F(\lambda)$ is bounded. Morever, using the same idea and integration by parts, one can see that $n^{th}$ derivative of $a$ must vanish at $1$.

Comment: I think you wrote $a(t)$ many times when you meant $F(\lambda)$.

Comment: Also: Care to explain how you showed some of these facts?

Comment: Where exactly do you think that I misplaced $F(\lambda)$?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I such got confused.

Comment: Have you tried approximating $a(t)$ uniformly by polynomials? It seems like the result easily follows from integration by parts if $a(t)$ is a polynomial

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but to no avail. The reason why approaching by polynomials will not work is that you have to fix the $\epsilon$ or the closeness of approaching polynomials first. But $\lambda$ being large enough will ruin the approximation.

Comment: I feel like the intuition is that the exponential is going to blow up the area between $a$ and the x-axis the closer one gets to 1. In order for $a$ to maintain an overall $0$ area it has to quickly move over the to the other side of the axis to counter-act the last area. This means that if $a$ isn't equivalently $0$, it has to oscillate wildly and without bound as it moves over to $0$, but you determined $a$ vanishes at 1. Contradiction. Now I'm trying to make this rigorous.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have been trying to make that idea rigorous for couple of days now. :-(